# How to push only specific folders from Master branch to gh-pages branch?

Tags: github, github-pages

I'm fairly new to github and web development in general.  So say I have all of my project files on my Master branch and I want to push only the files needed to make my page run on gh-pages. How would I tell it to only push certain files to the new gh-pages branch? For example, when you use gulp or grunt it makes a folder that is your rendered site for previewing your site. How would I push only the contents from that site folder to gh-pages without adding all of the other unecessary that are on the Master branch?

I've been using Jekyll recently because you can still push all of the files onto gh-pages and it still works.  But I have 2 repositories for a lot of my projects.  One repository has all of the source files and then the other repository has only the files I need to push a working site onto gh-pages.  I want to clean up my github page so it is more organized.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for the benefit of newcomers to Git branches / `gh-pages` that might stumble across this problem, I found the least complicated way of moving files or folders from a master branch to a gh-pages branch is to do the following.

```
# First switch to the gh-pages branch
git checkout gh-pages

# Next checkout the specific file you wish to add to the gh-pages branch
git checkout master -- <path/to/file/folders/on/master/branch>

# Perfom the commit
git commit -m "Updated index.html from master"

# And push
git push
```

Assuming the file(s) you are trying to add to the `gh-pages` branch exist on the `master` branch you shouldn't have any problems following the above steps.

Comment: Could you comment on https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing ? It's not clear to me what exactly "publish a page" does ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `nodejs` and `npm` you can use the [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) package from the command line to publish to a `gh-pages` branch from a specific directory. The `gh-pages` package has a [command line utility](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#command-line-utility).

> Installing the package creates a gh-pages command line utility. Run gh-pages --help to see a list of supported options.

**Note:** You mentioned using **`Gulp`** and there is an `npm` package called [`gulp-gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-gh-pages) that I use successfully to create `gulp` tasks to put into my deploy workflow.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I also had found a solution a couple of days ago.  Here is how I handled it:  I made my Main folder and then added a Master folder inside of that.  The Master folder includes all of my project files.  When I'm done with the project I cloned it into my Main folder and push all of the cloned files into a new gh-pages branch.  Then you just simply change the files you want in the cloned folder and push the changes into your gh-pages directory without affecting your Master project folder.

Comment: The packages above take out the work of managing the `gh-pages` branch.  You just need to figure out your work flow and have a build process into a temp folder that does not need to be part of the `master` branch in the repository. Once the build is complete, run the command with that folder as the source. Pretty simple really.

Comment: Also found a handy repo from Shakyshane for my future jekyll projects: https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for [git subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging).

> The idea of the subtree merge is that you have two projects, and one of the projects maps to a subdirectory of the other one and vice versa. 
>   When you specify a subtree merge, Git is smart enough to figure out that one is a subtree of the other and merge appropriately — it’s pretty amazing.

Comment: does seem a little overkill for jekyll though; if your jekyll instance is compatible with github, you can keep *only* the jekyll markup in the `gh-pages` branch and it will be served up just fine. This is the way it's done for most "project" Jekyll-sites, offered as a default on github.com

Comment: Awesome.  I will have to try out the subtree merge.  Also @maxheld, I am talking about the projects I have that are not based on Jekyll.  They are some older projects that I had to push into 2 separate repositories just so that I still had all of my source code and project files somewhere in case I need them.

Comment: That's a little thin. Can you provide an actual example how to set this up for gh-pages?